# How to combine the data of two cell arrays?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vector

I have two cell arrays `cellA` and `cellB` each having 1060 elements.The size of each cell within cell array `cellA` is `870*1` and the same for `cellB` is `16*1`. I want to combine these two into a third cell array `cellC`. Not combine the cells themselves but the data of each, such that after combining their size becomes `886*1`.

Ive tried these commands but they combine the cells and not the data within each

```
cellC = [cellA cellB];
cellC = [{cellA} {cellB}];
```

Comment: Why not make them 1060x870 and 1060x16 cell matrices first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
cellC=cellfun(@(x,y) [x y], cellA, cellB, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: If the elements are column vectors, you'll want to concatenate them vertically, i.e. [x;y] instead of [x y] inside the cellfun()

Comment: @CapeCode can this be generalized to more than 2 cellarrays? What if I have a with 1x1000 and b with 1x1000 and **c with 1x1000** and d... that should give you 4x1000?

Answer (score 1):

Convert each cell array to a matrix by concatenating cells horizontally; then concatenate those matrices vertically; and convert back to a cell array of columns:

```
cellC = mat2cell([[cellA{:}]; [cellB{:}]], numel(cellA{1})+numel(cellB{1}), [1 1]);
```

Example:

```
>> cellA = {(1:4).', (11:14).'};
>> cellB = {(101:103).', (111:113).'};
>> cellC = mat2cell([[cellA{:}]; [cellB{:}]], numel(cellA{1})+numel(cellB{1}), [1 1])
cellC = 
    [7x1 double]    [7x1 double]
>> cellC{:}
ans =
     1
     2
     3
     4
   101
   102
   103
ans =
    11
    12
    13
    14
   111
   112
   113
```

Answer (score 1):

I just do something simple like:

```
cellC = {cellA{:} cellB{:}};
```

This will result in a cell array that is 886 long.  From your question, I'm not sure if you wanted a regular array (which is what the other answers above will give) or a cell array.  If you're Ok with getting a cell array, this is a pretty simple way of doing it.